# Eclipse running JUnit5 tests throw java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"

Tags: eclipse, junit5

I have a simple JUnit project in a maven project.

When I have this simple test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import lombok.val;

class MyTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        val list = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6, 8, 5);
        val expected = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
        assertThat(list, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
    }

}
```

And I added the Junit5 library to the build path, I get this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I found that this happens, because I'm using hamcrest-2.1.jar as the dependency and eclipse is using a 1.3.0v20180420-1519.jar version in the JUnit5 library.

Is there any way to fix this, because I only have problems when I need to use methods that exists in the org.hamcrest.Matchers class. The ones that exist in the org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers don't give any problem.

I'm using eclipse 
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Build id: 20181214-0600

Thanks

Comment: From what I just found, the jar inside the .p2 is installed by eclipse and is signed. But the jar downloaded by maven is not signed. I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to this https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/issues/128 there's a fix for this problem. Just replace the .p2 version of the hamcrest jar by the maven hamcrest-core 1.3.

Comment: How could you do that? I have same issue .